# Tox does not find the requirements file

Tags: python, installation, tox

I have a Python module in which the `setup.py` script starts as follows:

```
import setuptools, pathlib

HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()
REQUIRES = (HERE / "requirements.txt").read_text().strip().split("\n")

setuptools.setup(
   install_requires=REQUIRES,
   long_description=README,
   ...
)
```

When I run the setup from the command line, like this:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

it runs fine. But when I run

```
tox
```

I get an error on line 5 in file setup.py:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

even though both the `requirements.txt` file and the `README.md` file remain in the same folder as `setup.py`.

Here is my `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py39

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    -r requirements.txt
commands =
    pytest
```

How can I make `tox` find my requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complementary answer to the correct one by `Erel`.

Depending on configuration, `tox` builds the project, installs the build artifact and then tests against it. This is a good thing as only then you test what you ship, and not what is in the source tree.

In order to not forget to include files in the `MANIFEST.in` file, I usually use the `check-manifest` tool/linter, see https://pypi.org/project/check-manifest/

### Two minor notes

- `python setup.py sdist` is deprecated, see https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html - you should use https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ instead
- using a `requirements.txt` in a `setup.py` is not recommended, see this classic article https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/ ; additionally, nowadays I would recommend to use `pip-tools` to pin dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the great information!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The problem was that `requirements.txt` was not included by my 'MANIFEST.in' file. I changet the file to:

```
include pyproject.toml
include *.md
include *.txt
include LICENSE
```

and now `tox` works.